# When to initialize mysql connections in node

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I'm trying to figure out what the best time to actually initialize connections for mysql in node is.

Am I supposed to create a pool of connections and then set them to some global so that all my models have access to the pool? Or am I supposed to initialize connections whenever I'm doing queries?(Seems bad).

I'm sure there's some "proper" way to do it, but I'm not really certain what the best way is.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to pool connections, then don't initialize connections right when they're needed. When not using a pool, you can just store connection information when your application is starting up, and use it when you need it:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'me',
  password: 'secret'
});
```

Then for single use cases:

```
connection.connect();
connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
  // we are done with the connection
  connection.end();

  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
});
```

If you're pooling, you should just create a connection pool when your application is starting and fetch connections when you need them. You should not make more than one pool.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'example.org',
  user: 'bob',
  password: 'secret'
});
```

Then when you need a connection, you'd do something like this:

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  connection.query( 'SELECT something FROM sometable', function(err, rows) {
    // we are done using the connection, return it to the pool
    connection.release();

    // the connection is in the pool, don't use it here
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After more research, think I've figured out the right way.

1) Create a connection pool on app start

2) Include that file in your models.

3) Get a connection from the pool.

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of keeping your code cleaner, I think you can also just invoke the pool object directly, according to the manual at https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql. This should abstract the logic for getting and releasing connections from the pool.

EG:

```
var result = yield pool.query("SELECT * FROM users");
```

(I'm using co-mysql with support for generators, but syntactically it should be the same w/out the callbacks)